# XPath Exclude Text From Child Element

Tags: xpath

I'm looking to get the output:

```
 50ml milk
```

From the following code:

```html
<ul class="ingredients-list__group">
  <li>50ml <a href="/glossary/milk" class="tooltip-processed">milk
<div class="tooltip">
      <h2
        class="node-title">Milk</h2> <span class="fonetic">mill-k</span>
        <p>One of the most widely used ingredients, milk is often referred to as a complete food. While cow…</p>
        </div>
        </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Currently I'm using the XPATH:

```
//ul[@class="ingredients-list__group"]/li
```

But getting:

```
50ml milk Milk mill-kOne of the most widely used ingredients, milk is often referred to as a complete food. While cowâ€¦
```

How do I exclude the stuff within the div/tooltip?

Comment: Please say which XPath version you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **`xpath`** 2.0:

```
//ul[@class="ingredients-list__group"]/li/concat(./text()[1], ./a/text()[1])
```

With **`xpath`** 1.0:

```
concat(//ul[@class="ingredients-list__group"]/li/text()[1], //ul[@class="ingredients-list__group"]/li/a/text()[1])'
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified using PHP, so xpath 1.0 and concat doesn't work! However, the second code is very close. I've adapted it to use the "|" merge operator, but it's outputting the two relevant sections (50ml & milk) as separate array items. Any ideas how to merge them at the point of query? As I have other <li>s to deal with.

Comment: @DrMikey, if PHP is a crucial tag in your case - you should have added it in your question + your current PHP code

Answer (score 0):

You can select the relevant text nodes using

```
//ul[@class="ingredients-list__group"]//
   text()[not(ancestor::div[@class='tooltip'])]
```

If you're in XPath 2.0 you can then put this in a call of string-join() to join these into a single string. If you're stuck with 1.0, you'll have to return multiple text nodes to the calling application and concatenate them together in the host language code.