# XPath in PHP using Concat Function

Tags: php, xpath

Following another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129305/xpath-exclude-text-from-child-element) on a similar topic, I've run into trouble trying to get the concat() function working with XPATH in PHP. As best I can tell, it's xpath 1.0 (using the default google app engine version of PHP).

Can anyone provide me with a simple working example of concat working in Xpath for PHP? I can't find one anywhere and can't get it to work myself.

Thanks

EDIT:
Sample code that is failing:

```
function testConcat(){

$webpage = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

    $html = file_get_contents('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147899/xpath-in-php-using-concat-function');
    $webpage->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

    $webpage_xpath = new DOMXPath($webpage);
    $query = 'concat(//h1,"hello")';
    $webpage_xpath = $webpage_xpath->query($query);


        return $webpage_xpath->item(0)->nodeValue;

}
print testConcat();
```

Comment: That's not the way to ask a question. We need to know what you tried and how it failed. You're clearly missing something basic and if you show us your code then we can tell you what you have misunderstood. My suspicion would be that you're treating the XPath result as a node-set when it's actually a string, but that's pure guesswork.

Comment: I've added a sample code that is failing.

Comment: I also asked you to say how it is failing.

Comment: If I knew how it was failing I might well known why. As it happens, I just know that it returns an empty results set

Comment: If you knew it returned an empty results set, that's a lot more than we knew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to access the results as if the expression returned a node-set

```
$webpage_xpath->item(0)->nodeValue
```

but actually it returns a string.

Use `DOMXPath::evaluate` rather than `DOMXPath::query` when you want a result other than a node-set.

Comment: Just for clarity for future readers, the code that needs changing is ` $webpage_xpath = $webpage_xpath->evaluate($query);


        return $webpage_xpath;`